# Admin user administration with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying out Devise for the first time. One of the things that I wanted to do is provide an interface for Admin users to create, find and edit users. Here's where I may have gone wrong.

I created a PeopleController class which inherits from ApplicationController that lists people and provides methods and views for creating and updating users. Everything works fine with one exception. When the admin user updates their own record, the session is cleared and they have to login again after saving it.

In this application I'm not using the registerable module. Only an admin user can create new users. What is the right way in devise to provide user management tools. Creating my own controller seems to have been the wrong path to take.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you very much for the help. This is essentially exactly what I am doing. I discovered a clue that helped me solve the problem of the user's session being cleared when they edit their own record in this wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

This is the line I needed:

```
sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
```

This method is located in Devise::Controllers::Helpers so I did this in my controller.

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
   include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
```

Then in my update method I call it only if the current_user.id equals the id that is being edited:

```
def update
  @person = User.find(params[:id])
  if @person.update_attributes(params[:user])
    sign_in @person, :bypass => true if current_user.id == @person.id
    redirect_to  person_path(@person), :notice  => "Successfully updated user."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Now if the current user edits their own record, the session is restored after it is saved.

Thanks again for your responses.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I manage users in one of my apps. I have only one `User` class generated with

```
rails g devise User
```

to which I added a `role` column with this migration:

```
class AddRoleToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :string, :default => "client"
  end
end
```

and my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  def admin?
    self.role == "admin"
  end
end
```

Then to create new users all you would have to do is provide a custom method in a controller (maybe even subclass `Devise::RegistrationsController`) like this:

```
# some_controller.rb
def custom_create_user
  if current_user.admin?
    User.create(:email => params[:email], password => params[:password])
    redirect_to(some_path, :notice => 'sucessfully updated user.')
  else
    redirect_to(some_other_path, :notice => 'You are not authorized to do this.')
  end
end
```

Comment: I would also recommend maybe going with a separate "Role" model, so that a user may have multiple roles if necessary. Would probably make everything easier too. Then a join model, maybe called "UserRole" which would have the user_id and role_id.

Comment: That's true, although I typically use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) when I need to define multiple roles or complex permissions.

Comment: I also use CanCan, but I still use a Separate Role Model. Check out this awesome wiki page Ryan Bates made: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model