# The rails spec for user model default admin value doesn't pass - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, default-value, modelattribute

I have the following problem: I'm doing a project where I'm supposed to fix some broken code in order to get into the Rails workshops. I'm supposed to make the User model spec pass. The spec checks for the default value of an admin attribute, and it looks like this:

```
it "by default isn't admin" do
    expect(User.new).to_not be_admin
  end
```

EDIT: I should clarify, that I didn't write the spec - the apps authors did it, I'm just supposed to make it pass. And I am not sure if I can rewrite it according to suggestions.

The migration looks like this:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

So when I create a new User in console, the default value for admin is indeed false, and the method `User.new.admin?` also returns false. This is how the new user looks like:

```
<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: false, firstname: nil, lastname: nil>
```

Despite all that, the spec does not pass. The failure message is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(User.new).to_not be_admin
       expected #<User:0xbe073dc> to respond to `admin?`
```

What am I missing? Oh, and this is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :reviews
  has_many :products
  validates :firstname, presence: true
  validates :lastname,  presence: true
end
```

Comment: Are you sure your test DB is set up properly and your migrations are run? Try `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare` and see if that helps?

Comment: Are you sure that be_admin produces User.admin? I think that you must use be_false

Comment: I did migrate and prepare the db. Changing the spec to be_false would check the whole model for validity, I think, not just the admin attribute. Check out the failure message above.

Answer (score 0):

Use rspec be methods, be_(something) doesn't produce Entity.(something)?

```
it "by default isn't admin" do
  user = User.new
  expect(user.admin).to be_false
end
```

[RSpec be method](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers)

Answer (score 0):

Your test is expecting `User` to have an `admin?` method but it does not look like it does.  You should probably rewrite the test `expect(User.new.admin).to be_false`.

Otherwise, you can add the method to your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def admin?
    self.role == "admin"
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if these specs can be rewritten. I'm just supposed to make them pass, someone else wrote them for me.

Comment: OK Rad I've updated answer with alternate solution.  You may need to tweak based on `admin` type (I am assuming `boolean`).

Comment: I tried to do it that way, but it didn't help. The output seemed to be looped, it printed one line over and over:     `# ./app/models/user.rb:14:in `admin?'`
.

Comment: OK I'm guessing here a bit but it might need to be `is_admin?`.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: That didn't work also. It's the weirdest thing, because when I create a User in the console it goes like this: `User.new.admin?` = `false`, and `User.new(admin: true).admin?` = `true`. So if the User model has Admin attribute which is a boolean, it gets the `#admin?` method by default, am I correct? So the spec should pass.

Comment: That is strange.  OK I've updated my answer one more time based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337352/admin-user-administration-with-devise once I realized you are using `Devise` (sorry I missed that originally).  Although I am not sure how you are able to check `admin?` in the console unless the method is defined somewhere...

Comment: Please check my answer above, I figured it out finally.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of variants of `admin?` method I made it to be

```
def admin?
end
```

And somehow it passed. Why didn't the default `admin?` method work, and I had to do it explicitly - no idea.